# UEFI and LVM causing BIOS to hang under various conditions

Tags: linux, fedora, lvm, grub, uefi

Using Fedora 23 with LVM on a Toshiba C50-B-021 laptop with UEFI,
the BIOS will hang on boot every time:

- the computer runs out of battery,
- it is turned off for more than a few seconds,
- a new kernel is installed,
- something causes the system to crash,
- and sometimes just because it feels like it.

To fix this, I use a live system to:

1. chroot into the existing system,
2. update the system,
3. regenerate the grub.cfg,
4. then reinstall grub

This is the sequence of commands I use to accomplish this task:

```
su -
cd /mnt
mount /dev/fedora/root ./
mount /dev/fedora/home home/
mount -t proc proc proc/
mount --rbind /sys sys/
mount --rbind /dev dev/
mount --rbind /var/run/ var/run/
chroot /mnt/
mount -a
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
grub2-install /dev/sda
```

Recently, through some random debugging, I found out that it will fix itself if I:

1. change from UEFI boot to CSM boot in the BIOS settings,
2. boot to the "insert a bootable drive" screen,
3. reboot and reverse the changes.

Most of the time this works, but sometimes it will just fix the hanging part, and leave me at a prompt asking for me to insert a bootable drive, in which case I use the previously mentioned process to fix the problem.

### How can I figure out why this is happening and fix the problem?

<sub>**Side note:** If you can figure out a better title for this, please edit it in.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Try using Intel BITS (in CSM), Intel CHIPSEC, Canonical FWTS, and Intel LUV-live on this box and look at the resulting test logs to see if system has defects that may be causing this. Check Toshiba site for firmware updates, and ask on their support forums.

Comment: How would I go about doing all of this?